# Error during import of an unmanaged solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I get a strange error when I am trying to import an unmanaged solution into an Dynamics CRM 2011 organization with Rollup 2.

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_LocalizedLabelCheck'.
>
> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'MetadataSchema.LocalizedLabel'. The duplicate key value is (9fe3ce29-44aa-4a70-aad1-d85dedf9f0e2, name, 1033, Sep 5 2011 1:35PM, 0).
>
> The statement has been terminated

I can find that GUID in table `MetadataSchema.LocalizedLabel` but there are lots of duplicates as expected!?

Does anyone have any ideas why I am getting this error during import?

Answer (score 1):

You experience imho an issue which should be resolved with the release of [Rollup 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2556167/en).
Install it and try to import the solution again.